# Can I set readyAsyncCalls limit in OkHttp?

Tags: okhttp

If many request occured using OkHttp over `maxRequestsPerHost` value.
that request will be enqueue and waiting.

I don't want using this queue and I want if request over `maxRequestsPerHost` then block request or throw Exception.
In ApacheHttpClient, set `setMaxConnPerRoute(60)` like this. if request over 60 other request didn't execute.

So.. Can I setting queue limit or connecton limit?